# Type error when using as="element" on a variable

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-2.0

I'm consuming a web service which returns escaped XML.  I need to un-escape it and do a transform on it.  I'm trying to figure out how to do that in a single transform given that I get this error:

> Required item type of value of variable $result is element(); supplied
>   value has  item type text()

with this XML:

```
  <MyServiceResponse>
    <MyServiceResult>&lt;?xml version=&quot;1.0&quot; encoding=&quot;UTF-8&quot;?&gt;
&lt;vector&gt;&lt;num&gt;1100070561&lt;/num&gt;&lt;/vector&gt;</MyServiceResult>
</MyServiceResponse>
```

using this stylesheet:

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" version="2.0" exclude-result-prefixes="xs">
    <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes"/>
    <xsl:template match="/MyServiceResponse">
        <xsl:variable name="result" as="element()">         
            <xsl:value-of select="MyServiceResult" disable-output-escaping="yes"/>
        </xsl:variable>
        <CustomerID  xmlns="http://myURL.com">
            <xsl:value-of select="$result/*"/>
        </CustomerID>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

I'm using Saxon-EE 9.6.0.4J

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well with Saxon EE you have full access to XSLT 3.0 or to Saxon's extension functions http://saxonica.com/html/documentation/functions/saxon/parse.html so I would simply parse the result with e.g. `<xsl:variable name="result" select="saxon:parse(MyServiceResult)" xmlns:saxon="http://saxon.sf.net/"/>`. That would give you a document node you can then output its contained nodes, e.g. `<xsl:copy-of select="$result/node()"/>`.

Comment: Thank you very much Martin. Both saxon:parse() and parse-xml() worked perfectly. I went with the latter as it is part of the 3.0 spec.  My first 3.0 stylesheet!  ;-)